# In Rails, how do I limit which attributes can be updated, without preventing them from being created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessible

I have a situation where an attribute can be created through a JSON API. But once it is created, I want to prevent it from ever being updated.

This constraint causes my first solution, which is using `attr_accessible`, to be insufficient. Is there a nice way to handle this type of situation in rails, or do I have to perform a manual check in the `update` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`attr_readonly`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods/attr_readonly), this will allow the value to be set on creation, but ignored on update.

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_readonly :name
end


> User.create(name: "lorem")
> u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, name: "lorem">
> u.name = "ipsum"
=> "ipsum"
> u.save
=> true
> User.first.name
=> "lorem"
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be an easy way :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a nice way to do that as far as I know, you have to write a custom filter

```
before_update :prevent_attributes_update

def prevent_attribute_updates
  %w(attr1, attr2).each do |a|
    send("#{attr1}=", send("#{attr1}_was")) unless self.send("#{attr1}_was").blank?
  end
end
```