# Rails how to restrict attribute updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, beforeupdate

I got an Object, **Rating**, with 2 fields, **user_id** and **value**.

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
     def change
       create_table :ratings do |t|
          t.belongs_to :user
          t.integer :user_id
          t.decimal :value
       end
     end
end
```

On create i want to set user_id and value to the given values from the Controller:

```
@rating = Rating.create(user_id: 1, value: 2)
```

But after i created it, it should not be possible to change the *user_id attribute*. Just the *value attribute*. So after that:

```
@rating.update(user_id: 2, value: 3)
```

@rating.user_id should still return 1, but value should be 3.

My idea was to use *before_update* to revert the changes, but that does not look right to me.

Is the another way to do it?

i hope i could make it more clear whats my problem..

Thanks

### Update

The Controller looks like this:

```
  def create
     Rating.create(rating_params)
  end

   def edit
     Rating.find(params[:id]).update(rating_params)
   end

   private

   def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:user_id, :value)
   end
```

Comment: This sounds like a complete mess to me... Why do you have **two** columns for what should clearly be a single boolean attribute? Do not not `permit` certain attributes, or have some `policies` in place for certain user roles..... Most importantly though, you need to *show us your code*. We cannot answer this question in its current vague form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Rails, how do I limit which attributes can be updated, without preventing them from being created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735935/in-rails-how-do-i-limit-which-attributes-can-be-updated-without-preventing-the)

Comment: @TomLord: `changeable` and `not_changeable` are likely just terribly chosen fake names for real attributes. `photo` and `email`, for example.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: thats that i ment. didnt realise it utill the awnser.

Comment: @IoaneSharvadze: Thanks thats what i was looking for, didnt found it before.

Comment: @Clemny You almost certainly shouldn't be preventing changing attributes **in the model**! You need to put this logic *in the controller*. Do you have a controller action that's updating this record? Can you show us?

Comment: @Clemny: those answers are from 5 years ago. not sure about `attr_readonly`, but `attr_accessible` is no longer in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with some strong_params. Simply don't allow `user_id` when updating. Something along these lines:

```
class RatingsController
  def create
    @rating = Rating.create(create_rating_params)
    ...
  end

  def update
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
    @rating.update_attributes(update_rating_params)
    ...
  end

  private

  def create_rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:user_id, :value)
  end

  def update_rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:value)
  end
end
```